# PouchDB - start local, replicate later

Tags: couchdb, replication, pouchdb, cloudant

Does it create any major problems if we always create and populate a PouchDB database locally first, and then *later* sync/authenticate with a centralised CouchDB service like Cloudant?

Consider this simplified scenario:

- You're building an accommodation booking service such as hotel search or airbnb
- You want people to be able to favourite/heart properties without having to create an account, and will use PouchDB to store this list

  - i.e. the idea is to not break their flow by making them create an account when it isn't strictly necessary
- If users wish to opt in, they can *later* create an account and receive credentials for a "server side" database to sync with

At the point of step 3, once I've created a per-user CouchDB database server-side and assigned credentials to pass back to the browser for sync/replication, how can I link that up with the PouchDB data already created? i.e.

1. Can PouchDB somehow just reuse the existing database for this sync, therefore pushing all existing data up to the hosted CouchDB database, or..
2. Instead do we need to create a new PouchDB database and then copy over all docs from the existing (non-replicated) one to this new (replicated) one, and then delete the existing one?

I want to make sure I'm not painting myself into any corner I haven't thought of, before we begin the first stage, which is supporting non-replicated PouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of data you want to sync from the server, but in general, you can replicate a pre-existing database into a new one with existing documents, just so long as those document IDs don't conflict.

So probably the best idea for the star-rating model would be to create documents client-side with IDs like `'star_<timestamp>'` to ensure they don't conflict with anything. Then you can aggregate them with a map/reduce function.

Comment: Thanks. There would be no content generated "server side" before the first sync so no risk of conflict.